# Overflow-y scroll causes content to cut off

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I currently have a container that has a max-height of 800px. It also has overflow-y: scroll. What I am trying to accomplish is simple (Probably not so simple, hence why I am asking you guys!).

I want to continue to have this overflow-y scroll. However, I have content which gets cut off. I have a div with class future-dropdown which I want content inside to purposely overlay this container. If you take a look at the code snippet, my content inside the div gets cut off as it should because of the overflow-y scroll.

How can I get around this and still have this? I still need this scrollable container but I also need a way to still have my content show in that position.

Suggestions please!

```css
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .scroll-list {
        max-height: 800px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 5px solid blue;
        width: 400px;
    }
    
    li {
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-color: white;
        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        list-style-type: none;
        background: lightgray;
        /* margin: 0 auto; */
    }
    
    .future-dropdown {
        position: relative;
        left: 200px;
    }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <title></title>
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <!--[if lt IE 7]>
                <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
            <![endif]-->
            <div class="scroll-list">
                <ul>
                    <li>Content <div class="future-dropdown">Future dropdown</div></li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <script src="" async defer></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: And if you change the width of .scroll-list?

Comment: I need the width to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this

```
li {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left; /*Change from center to left*/
    list-style-type: none;
    background: lightgray;
    padding: 20px; /*Add some padding*/
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
}
```

Let me know if that help you!

Comment: Hi. I have a weird case where I need the content to be visible in that position where it was placed. This has nothing to do with alignment. My goal is to have the the content show with having overflow-y still scrollable. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code snippet.

I've added following css,

```
.future-dropdown1 {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
}
.future-dropdown2 {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Since positioning the `div` with `left` property would cause it to start from the defined pixel position, it was getting cropped.

```css
* {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .scroll-list {
        max-height: 800px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 5px solid blue;
        width: 400px;
    }
    
    li {
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-color: white;
        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        list-style-type: none;
        background: lightgray;
        /* margin: 0 auto; */
    }
    
    .future-dropdown1 {
        position: relative;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .future-dropdown2 {
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <title></title>
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <!--[if lt IE 7]>
                <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
            <![endif]-->
            <div class="scroll-list">
                <ul>
                    <li>Content <div class="future-dropdown1">Future dropdown</div></li>
                    <li>Content <div class="future-dropdown2">Future dropdown</div></li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <script src="" async defer></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I want the content to be visible outside of its 400px container. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who came here because there is content hidden behind the scrollbar, check the html, body, and/or container's width. For me, changing the width from 100vw to 100% solved it.

Comment: If you can add some code/CSS example as well as clarification this would be really helpful.

Comment: You may also with to check out the `Overflow` CSS property.